# Android notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать динамический GridView, что бы в onCreate грузился GridView с превьюшками и по нажатию обновить (если есть что то новое) добавилось в UI 
и как мне это выполнить?
Вот мой код

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView grid;
    ImageAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<String> arrayThumbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayBig_image = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayAuthor = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayDate = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] arraymThumbs;
    String[] arrayBimages;
    String[] arrayauthor;
    String[] arraydescription;
    String[] arraydate;

    final static String TAG_ITEM = "img_list";
    final static String TAG_THUMBNAILS = "thumbnail";
    final static String TAG_BIG_IMAGE = "big_image";
    final static String TAG_AUTHOR = "author";
    final static String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    final static String TAG_DATE = "event_date";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        BackTask task = new BackTask();
        task.execute();

        try {
            JSONObject result = task.get();
            if(result != null){
            JSONArray jarray = result.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
            for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jrss = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                arrayThumbs.add(jrss.getString(TAG_THUMBNAILS));
                arrayBig_image.add(jrss.getString(TAG_BIG_IMAGE));
                arrayAuthor.add(jrss.getString(TAG_AUTHOR));
                arrayDescription.add(jrss.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                arrayDate.add(jrss.getString(TAG_DATE));
            }}
            else{
                AlertDialog.Builder alertNetworkError = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alertNetworkError.setMessage("нет подключения к интернету");
                alertNetworkError.setNegativeButton("Выйти", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();                           
                    }                       
                });
                alertNetworkError.create();
                alertNetworkError.show();
            }
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayThumbs);
            grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View view,  int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageGallery.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", position);
                    intent.putExtra("big_images", arrayBimages);
                    intent.putExtra("author", arrayauthor);
                    intent.putExtra("description", arraydescription);
                    intent.putExtra("date", arraydate);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }       
            });

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){        
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            BackTask task = new BackTask();
            task.execute();

            try {
                JSONObject result = task.get();
                if(result != null){
                JSONArray jarray = result.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jrss = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrayThumbs.add(jrss.getString(TAG_THUMBNAILS));
                    adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayThumbs);
                    arrayBig_image.add(jrss.getString(TAG_BIG_IMAGE));
                    arrayAuthor.add(jrss.getString(TAG_AUTHOR));
                    arrayDescription.add(jrss.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                    arrayDate.add(jrss.getString(TAG_DATE));

                }}
                else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertNetworkError = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    alertNetworkError.setMessage("нет подключения к интернету");
                    alertNetworkError.setNegativeButton("Выйти", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();                           
                        }                       
                    });
                    alertNetworkError.create();
                    alertNetworkError.show();
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 JSONArray jarray = result.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jrss = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    arrayThumbs.add(jrss.getString(TAG_THUMBNAILS));
                    adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayThumbs);
                    arrayBig_image.add(jrss.getString(TAG_BIG_IMAGE));
                    arrayAuthor.add(jrss.getString(TAG_AUTHOR));
                    arrayDescription.add(jrss.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                    arrayDate.add(jrss.getString(TAG_DATE));
```

вот тут не совсем понятно, что ты делаешь, логика должна быть такой

1. ты грузишь новые картинки и если они есть
2. добавляешь их в коллекцию и вызываешь adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); (этот метод, только обновит вьюху, сам он не обновляет данные)

как вариант, можно просто удалять данные из адаптера и вложить туда новые,
еще вариант делать новые адаптер, но это нерационально

и в твоем случае хорошо бы было сделать объект Image с нужными полями и хранить эти объекты в одной коллекции, вместо вот етого

```
ArrayList<String> arrayThumbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayBig_image = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayAuthor = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayDate = new ArrayList<String>();
```